# Scala Optional Non-Capture Group acting Lazy?

Tags: regex, scala

I am not looking for a regex to match phone numbers. This is simply my use case. I want to know why my regex isn't including an optional non-matching group within the capture.

To better illuminate my specific use case, a bit of an introduction. I  am trying to match phone numbers. I have a working regex with the exception of when an extension is used.

My regex (a bit long, but comprehensive):

```
((?:\+{0,2}\d{1,3})?[-.()\/* ]*?\d{3}[-.()\/* ]*?\d{3}[-.()\/* ]*?\d{4}[-.()\/* ]*?(?:(?:x|ext)[:]?[ ]*\d+)?)
```

A shortened version to illustrate my issue:

```
(\d{4}[-.()\/* ]*?(?:(?:x|ext)[:]?[ ]*\d+)?)
```

Where:

`(...)` is my capture group

`\d{4}` four digits

`[-.()\/* ]*?` various separators 0-infinite times (non-greedy)

`(?:...)` non-capture group

`x|ext` extension identifier

`[:]?` ":" 0-1 time

`[ ]*` " " 0-infinite times

`\d+` digit 1-infinite times

`(?:...)?` non-capture group 0-1 time

So `1234 ext 567` should match, but only `1234` does

Regex101 link: [regex101.com/r/NRQhTl/1](https://regex101.com/r/NRQhTl/2)

If I remove the `?`, to make the group not optional it works just fine:

```
(\d{4}[-.()\/* ]*?(?:(?:x|ext)[:]?[ ]*\d+))
```

It seems like the `?` is making it lazy but then also won't match numbers that do not have an extension.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where do scala and lazy-evaluation come into play? As far as I can tell this is strictly a regex question.

Comment: `*?` is a *lazy* regex. If I understand it correctly, you want just `*` after `[...]`, not a `*?`. The tag `lazy-evaluation` is incorrect, it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @emsimpson92 I don't think this is a duplicate. While I am trying to match phone numbers, my question isn't about finding a regex to match phone numbers. Rather, why is the extension non-matching group acting lazy. It's far more specific

Comment: @AndreyTyukin you are correct, lazy regex is what I meant

Comment: It's not the extension group acting lazily. It's the `[-.()\/* ]*?` that matches zero characters and then gives up, because it's "good enough".

Comment: @AndreyTyukin that makes sense. I that hadn't occurred to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the lazy `*?` quantifier after the separator-symbols, then it seems to work just fine:

```
(\d{4}[-.()\/* ]*(?:(?:x|ext)[:]?[ ]*\d+)?)
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NRQhTl/3).

The reason why your `foo[bar]*?(?:extension)?`-regex stops matching immediately after `foo` is because the `*?` quantifier forces it to stop as early as possible, matching exactly zero characters from `bar` and then skipping the non-capturing extension group.

You might also consider moving the `[-.()\/* ]*` part into the `(?: ... )?` as well, because otherwise it will match periods that aren't followed by a proper extension.

I'm not sure what you tried with the `()` there, to be honest: is it really supposed to match `1234) ext 5678`?

Comment: The parans are for use primarily for the area code and country code. For the shortened example they are extraneous. I build the regex using components, and that piece is my generic "separator". It was lazy exactly for that reason, so I may need to be less generic